# Explaining .call() in layman terms. Assistance in understanding it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see this example in the mozilla docs. with the following explaination:

"In this purely constructed example, we create anonymous function and use call to invoke it on every object in an array. The main purpose of the anonymous function here is to add a print function to every object, which is able to print the right index of the object in the array. Passing the object as this value was not strictly necessary, but is done for explanatory purpose."

```
var animals = [
  {species: 'Lion', name: 'King'},
  {species: 'Whale', name: 'Fail'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    this.print = function () {
      console.log('#' + i  + ' ' + this.species + ': ' + this.name);
    }
  }).call(animals[i], i);
}
```

What I don't understand is what is call doing here. if we didn't have it, wouldn't we still be cycling thru the anon function and consoling the value? Does this do anything with closure? I am just trying to understand how .call() is used here and why.

Comment: "Layman" terms? Do laypeople know anything about programming?

Comment: You might want to read MDN's [introduction into the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: And after you get the 'this' keyword down.. [call reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: I unders *this*, I just don't understand the usage of ".call()" here as wouldn't the loop pass in the proper reference? So why use call. I am not wrapping my brain around it.

Answer (score 5):

`call` invokes a function in a specific context.  In this case, it is setting `this` to `animals[0]` and `animals[1]`.  Without it, `this` in the context of the function wouldn't be set (or rather it would be set to `window`).

Comment: animals[0].say();
animals[1].say(); ok - i get it now, thanks a bunch.